# Find a and b values so a given function is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, entire-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

**The Problem**:
Let $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be an entire function.

If $g(z)=au^2(x,y) - bv^2(x,y)$ find values for a and b so $g(z)$ is a harmonic function.

**My attempt to find a solution**:

Well since I know that $f(z)$ is entire, the Cauchy-Riemann equations must hold, then:

$U_x=U_y$ and $V_x=-V_y$.

If $f(z)$ is entire, then its components are harmonic, hence:

$U_{xx} = -U_{yy}$ and $V_{xx}=-V_{yy}$

With all this information, I procceed to derivate $g(z)$ (twice) in terms of x and then in terms of y. So I can fulfill Laplace's equation and make $g(z)$ harmonic:

$g_{xx} + g_{yy}=0$.

I do this and end up with an expression that equals 0. The problem is, I don't know how to continue after this. I don't know if I lack another condition, or how to apply the information provided by the fact that $f(z)$ is entire correctly.
If I replace the conditions so everything is in terms of x (or y) I end up with an expression that equals 0 but contains both u and v, and I don't realize how to obtain values for a and b. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you compute the Laplacian of $g$? Did you take into account that $u$ and $v$ are *squared* in $g(z)=au^2(x,y) - bv^2(x,y)$ ?

Comment: MartinR Yes. I took that into account. I could edit the post and add the $g_(xx)$ and $g_(yy)$ expressions i've calculated.

Comment: There is an error in your Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product rule for computing the Laplacian of $g$ gives
$$
 \Delta g = 2 a(u u_{xx} + u_x^2 + u u_{yy} + u_y^2)
- 2 b(v v_{xx} + v_x^2 + v v_{yy} + v_y^2)
$$
Since $u$ and $v$ are harmonic and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations $u_x = v_y$, $u_y = -v_x$, this simplifies to
$$
 \Delta g = 2 (a-b)(u_x^2 + v_x^2) = 2(a-b) |f'(z)|^2
$$
which means that $g$ is harmonic if $a=b$ or if $f$ is constant.

*Remark:* In the case $a=b$ we have
$$
 g(z) = a (u^2(z) - v^2(z)) = a \operatorname{Re}(f(z)^2) 
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! My Laplacian was correct, but I made a silly mistake at writing the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Horrible handwriting is to blame haha.